# How to get the names of ALL objects that are related to an object via apex?

Tags: apex

The input is going to be a String containing the parent object name (say, Custom_Parent__c) and I would like the method to return me the names of ALL of its child objects (the output format doesn't matter... List, comma separated, etc are all OK).

How can this be done? Thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Set<String> results = new set<String>();
for( ChildRelationship r: Custom_Object__c.SObjectType.getDescribe().getChildRelationships())
    results.add(string.valueOf(r.getChildSObject()));
System.debug(string.join(new List<String>(results),',');
```

This outputs a comma delimited list of related objects. See documentation for more details on ChildRelationship.

Comment: Amazing. Thank you!